# Response to "Excuse me" when some one wants to pass you

Tags: conversation

It has happened to me a lot that when  I am searching for an item in aisle in a supermarket and somebody says  "excuse me" and passes me. What is a natural response to excuse myself here? What should I say?

Comment: Apart from "You are excused", which sounds haughty, there is not really an answer nor a need for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the Uk the most common response is...." [Silence] ", occasionally, it accompanied with a scowl - meaning "How dare you ask ME to move out of your way... I'm far too important!" or "Oh, I'm Sorry".  Brits do tend to apologise at every opportunity - even if it's not our fault!

I usually try to smile sweetly as I apologise :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Pakistan, its considered to give space and say nothing. Some people reply back saying "Excused" which feels a bit strange.